# How to move Flutter SDK to another directory

Tags: directory, sdk, flutter

I've installed Flutter SDK on my HDD and I want to move it to the SSD
can I move to another directory in the SSD ?
if I can please tell me how to move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their are two way of doing this

1. Go to

> `File-> Settings -> Under languages & framework section choose flutter

Their is an option for flutter SDK path. From here you can relocate your SDK path.

2. Try restarting Android studio if that doesn't solve your problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

you can download flutter sdk from here
[Download Flutter sdk](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

and save it where you want to placed
you just need to change the path of Environment Variables here
[Change Environment Variable Path](https://dartcode.org/docs/configuring-path-and-environment-variables/)